# Postsharp tracing on/off in runtime?

Tags: c#, trace, postsharp

Can anyone tell me, if in PostSharp, I somehow can turn on/off tracing in runtime? I need to write less code, so lately I could simply remove it. Tracing functionality is temporarily required.

Maybe there's an alternative to PostSharp with runtime on/off feature?

**Update 1:** I've come up with idea, but I don't know if it's good. Here's an example

```
    public class Smth
    {
        private long i = 0;

        [TraceAttribute]
        public void Execute()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Execute call" + i++);
            Thread.Sleep(200);
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class TraceAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
    {
        public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
        {
            if(Manager.IsEnabled)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Entering {0}", args.Method.Name));
            }
        }

        public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs args)
        {
            if(Manager.IsEnabled)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Leaving {0}", args.Method.Name));
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Manager
    {
        public static bool IsEnabled { get; set; }

        static Manager()
        {
               IsEnabled = true;
        }
    }
```

By changing IsEnabled property I was able to turn on/off tracing...
Any other suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean temporary? If you want to create an aspect for tracing, you can apply it using multicasting (1 line of code) and then remove it when done. IF you want to configue it via a config then just setup your aspect to work with a config. Why not just use .net built in tracing?

Comment: I need to make trace-logs for plenty of methods, so I choosed PostSharp, but I also need to have runtime on/off ability. This trace-logs are temporary feature, later it'll be removed -> so I don't whan't to integrate it in my program -> so It'll be easy to remove it later

Comment: Are you trying to have the ability to turn on/off the tracing within a single production build? Or have the ability to toggle between builds.

Comment: @JasonCoyne I was assuming without a rebuild since he said runtime which lead me to believe a config setting. Otherwise I would go a much different route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is fine (as long as it's temporary). Easily apply the aspect using multicasting. See my articles http://www.sharpcrafters.com/blog/post/Day-2-Applying-Aspects-with-Multicasting-Part-1.aspx and http://www.sharpcrafters.com/blog/post/Day-3-Applying-Aspects-with-Multicasting-Part-2.aspx

Disclaimer: I'm assuming the OP wants to do this without a rebuild since he said runtime which leads me to believe he wants a config setting. Otherwise I would suggest a much different route